# How to create an automated application tour / walkthrough?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, web-applications, user-interface

I am creating an angular-js based web application. I want to create an automated walkthrough/app-tour for the same - just like we see on google or facebook when they release some  new features/buttons.

This is to ask the community if they  can direct me to some tutorials. Also, I would like to create text boxes pointing at my features, say some button in the app. How do I make sure that this text box is positioned at the same place as the button?

Comment: It is unlikely that you get a good answer on this one, as you show you no research effort by yourself nor do you show what you have tried until now. I recommend to try a solution by yourself, then ask for improvement-help. To the topic: You could possibly use a simple system to check whether or not a user is on your new version for the first time, then cycle through a routine that makes changes to the DOM (Highlighting etc)

Comment: let me google that for you... http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/11-awesome-jquery-site-tour-plugins-for-guiding-users-with-style/

:-)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [IntroJS](http://www.introjs.com/) library which is simple, easy to use and free. Check the site, click the green button 'Show me how' to get an intro to intro!

Comment: Updated link http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/